# How to use ngfor in grid-list by material

Tags: angular, angular-material, grid

I want to implement a dynamic grid list with Angluar material. but I have some problems.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "abc": "sdfgsdfgs",
        "test": "dfgdfgdfgdfg"
    },
    {
       "abc": "dfgsdfgsdfg",
        "test": "dfgfgfgfgr"
    },
    {
        "abc": "sdfgsdfgs",
        "test": "asdfstest"
    },
]
```

And in the HTML I want to use `ngFor` to loop this JSON data and to show in a gird list.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="7:1">
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <u>abc</u>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <u>test</u>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of datas">
      <mat-grid-tile>
        {{ item.abc}}
        {{ item.test}}
      </mat-grid-tile>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

the expected result should look like this:

`````
abc               test
-------------------------------
sdfgsdfgs        dfgdfgdfgdfg
dfgsdfgsdfg      dfgfgfgfgr


````

How can I loop this?
`````

Comment: why u dont use ngFor in the mat-grid-tile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the loop on `mat-grid-tile`.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="7:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <u>abc</u>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <u>test</u>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <ng-container>
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of datas">
      {{ item.abc}}
      {{ item.test}}
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </ng-container>
</mat-grid-list>
```

For edited question:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="7:1">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <u>abc</u>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <u>test</u>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of datas">
        <mat-grid-tile>
            {{ item.abc}}
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            {{ item.test}}
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </ng-container>
</mat-grid-list>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mn-angular-grid-list)

Comment: Hi Mauhan, I have tried your solution, but there is a problem, by looping the item.abc and item.test will be created in one mat-grid-tile, that is actually not what I want. it should be in mat-rid-tile seperately.

Comment: @user1938143 check created stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

If your table headers are dynamic but these are the same for all indexes of your array you need to do the following

*component.ts*

```
get gridHeaders(): Array<string> {
    return Object.keys(this.datas[0]);
}
```

*component.html*

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="7:1">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let head of gridHeaders">
        <u>{{ head }}</u>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of datas">
        {{ item.abc}}
        {{ item.test}}
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```