# Angular material - mat-grid-list with parent and children components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to create grid list using two components. Parent and child. But it doesn't show anything.
parent(app-messages):

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
<app-message-item 
  *ngFor="let message of messages" 
  [message]="message"
  (deleteMessage)="deleteMessage(message._id)"
  (openUpdateDialog)="openUpdateDialog(message._id)"
  >
</app-message-item>
</mat-grid-list>
```

child(app-message-item):

```
<mat-grid-tile>
  <p>
    {{ message.created_at | date:'medium' }}
  </p>
  <div [innerHTML]="message.content"></div>
  <img [src]="message.fileImage ? environment+message.path : message.path" height="100"> 
  <button (click)="onDelete(message._id)" class="del">x</button>
  <button (click)="onUpdate(message._id)" class="del">Modify</button>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Can you also show the business logic you have written? your component ts files

Comment: I don't think it will help, because it's just getting data with parent component and passing it to child. Btw. data is good, because it all show up, without grid.

Comment: Ok, found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112167/how-to-use-ngfor-in-grid-list-by-material